# Emacs keyboard shortcut to insert \label{} \\ and a new line in math mode.

Tags: math-mode, editors, emacs

So, I'm using emacs with auctex to edit my latex documents. It's been a while since last time I used it, but I still remember my shortcuts. Except one.

While editing equations inside and align environment, you have to add `\\` at the end of each line, and add a label if you want reference that line specifically. I remember that emacs had a keyboard shorcut for that. You would use the shorcut and emacs automatically added `\label{numer} \\` followed by a line break.

What shortcut is that? I tried <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>, but that simply inserts a new line followed by a `\item`.

EDIT: Seems that C-c-( key should be doing the trick, but it just inserts a label for me.

I got both auctex and emacs from the repositories. My emacs version is 32.1.1. If I use C-h a and type in "LaTeX-amsmath-env-alignat" (or even just "amsmath") it doesn't find any matches, so I guess it's not defined. The major/minor modes I use for editing latex documents are "LaTeX/S Ref".

Comment: The variable `LaTeX-amsmath-label` contains this, which should be inserted by Reftex if it is bound to the usual key C-c-( (control-C "(").  If this doesn't work, well, something's wrong...

Comment: @Charles Stewart: That key combination successfully inserts a label wherever I am, but doesn't insert `\\` or a line break. It's what I've been using so far, since it's way better than typing a label. But I was sure there was a key for labeling and line breaking all in one.=/

Comment: Reftex should look at the environment you're in, and insert the full string.  To help try and figure out what is wrong: what version of Emacs are you using? Where did you get Auctex?  Is the function  LaTeX-amsmath-env-alignat defined (use C-h a, apropos-function, to check)?

Comment: @Charles:I got both auctex and emacs from the repositories. My emacs version is 32.1.1. If I use `C-h a` and type in "LaTeX-amsmath-env-alignat" (or even just "amsmath") it doesn't find any matches. The major/minor modes I use for editing latex documents are "LaTeX/S Ref".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got it. Back when I wasn't using Reftex I had to add this line to my *.emacs* file:
`(add-hook 'LaTeX-mode-hook (lambda () (LaTeX-add-environments '("align" LaTeX-env-label))))` because auctex alone didn't recognize the `align` environment. Now that I'm using Reftex, this line was causing it to misbehave. Removing it solved my problem. The shortcut that does what I was asking for is: <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>.